Passive sentences in German - need help from a native
I am studying the passive form of verbs for my M.A in Formal Linguistics.
I was wondering whether a native speaker of German could help me out with the following sentences. I know some German myself, but I don't have the same level of competence of a native speaker.
Here they are:
1. Ich wurde zwei Bücher gegeben.
2. Ich wurde Deutsch in der Schule gelehrt.
3. Ich bin schon diese Frage gestellt worden.
4. Ich wurde von dieser Frau geholfen.
I'm interested in whether these sentences are acceptable or not, because I would be interested in how languages with a rich system handle passivization.
I have one further question: where exactly do you put the direct object in German sentences? Usually it's at the end but it's not always the case:
Ich habe schon mal diesen Kuchen gegessen.
Ich habe die Zeitung im Park gelesen.
Are these two sentences correct?

I’m far from a native German speaker (in fact my German isn’t particularly good), but I instinctively want to use mir instead of ich in 1–3 (and ist instead of bin in 3, of course). The dative alternation somehow just sounds odd to me for some reason – though I don’t know if my gut is reliable here. As for the DO question, I’m pretty sure both are fine. I think “Ich habe im Park die Zeitung gelesen” is equally right, but “Ich habe dieses Kuchen schon mal gegessen” sounds odd to me.

Does this answer your question? Can you say "Ich wurde (etwas) gegeben"?

Those are two questions, and we prefer to have one at a time. For your first question, let me just point out that the second sentence happens to be correct because “lehren” is a very peculiar verb that takes two accusative objects, so it will not be covered by answers to similar questions about the passive voice.

"I have a further question..." if you have two questions, please post two questions, not one.

There are nö direct objects. Nor indirekt. That is an english grammar concept, not a german one

I (native German speaker) agree with @JanusBahsJacquet about sentences 1 to 3. I would think the same applies to 4, though there might be regional differences. While it might be true that lehren is special, as Carsten says, I would think this is archaic and mir wurde gelehrt would be more common in modern German.

I want to thank everybody for the answers. Next time I have two questions, I will post them separately then.  I had a feeling sentences 1, 3 and 4 were wrong, but I wanted to be 100% sure, so thanks again.  I suppose then that you can say something like "Ich wurde gefragt" too, since fragen takes two accusative objects.


I'm interested in whether these sentences are acceptable or not, because I would be interested in how languages with a rich system handle passivization.

1, 3, 4 aren't. Those examples feature competing subjects and that makes no sense. You can only have single or coordinated subjects. That's an implicit rule of human languages in general I think.

Ich wurde zwei Bücher gegeben.

Here your first subject is Ich and you conjugated the auxiliary for it, and then you introduce a competing subject zwei Bücher. That does not work. Your other examples 3 and 4 suffer from the same mistake. Your example 2 is slightly different. I discuss it later.

Let me show you a valid active sentence along with a valid passive voice sentence:

Der Mann gibt mir den Schlüssel.
Von dem Mann wird mir der Schlüssel gegeben.

See how the accusative object den Schlüssel in the active sentence becomes the subject der Schlüssel in the passive sentence? While the subject of the active sentence becomes an adverbial of origin. Those are made with von+dative in German. Completely optional by the way. The dative object mir in the active sentence stays the dative object mir in the passive sentence.
This is how you must build the passive voice in accusative languages as German. (There's actually some more ways to build passive voice sentences in German, but your idea with competing subjects is not one of those.)

If you wanted to heal your examples, you had to introduce a dative object mir as I did in my example, and conjugate the verb for the subject.

Mir werden zwei Bücher gegeben.
Mir ist diese Frage schon gestellt worden.
Mir wurde von dieser Frau geholfen.


About your second example:

Ich wurde Deutsch in der Schule gelehrt.

This is tricky because the verb lehren is one of the few verbs that take two accusative objects. So when you have an active sentence as

Man lehrte mich Deutsch in der Schule.

you can indeed make a passive sentence as yours from it. As the accusative object mich becomes the subject, the second accusative object Deutsch stays an accusative object, and the original subject man is simply dropped in the passive sentence.
But that sounds a bit clumsy. Much more common is the verb beibringen:

Man brachte mir Deutsch in der Schule bei.

The passive voice is again:

Mir wurde Deutsch in der Schule beigebracht.

This verb also allows for the alternative passive with bekommen that turns the dative object into the subject instead of the accusative object. This is a particular feature of German; in most other languages you can't do this. It's common to say:

Ich bekam Deutsch in der Schule beigebracht.



I have one further question: where exactly do you put the direct object in German sentences? Usually it's at the end but it's not always the case: Ich habe schon mal diesen Kuchen gegessen. Ich habe die Zeitung im Park gelesen.

Word order is tricky in German. Please see my recent post on the topic.

Thank you for your kind answer!

It doesn’t affect the acceptability in German, but you’re misinterpreting the intended structure of the example sentences. They are based on the English ability to promote either direct or indirect object to subject in passive constructions – but even in English, it’s not both that are not promoted. The non-promoted element retains its original role, and they are intended as objects here, not subjects (the NPs chosen just don’t distinguish nominative from accusative). Had it been a cake instead of two books, it would have been, “Ich wurde den Kuchen gegeben”, not “*der Kuchen”.

Later thought: can “the alternative passive with bekommen that turns the dative object into the subject instead of the accusative object” not also be used with 1 and 3? That seems to be exactly parallel to what English does when promoting indirect objects in passive constructions (except English uses the same verb for both). Are “Ich bekam zwei Bücher gegeben” and “Ich bekam schon diese Frase gestellt” grammatical?

Those are grammatical, and the latter phrasing is even common. English does a similar thing indeed.

E.g. Ich bekam zwei Bücher geschenkt. is also very common.


Mir wurden zwei Bücher gegeben.
Mir wurde Deutsch in der Schule gelehrt.
Mir ist diese Frage schon gestellt worden.
Mir wurde von dieser Frau geholfen.

There are several possibilities for the word order, depending on which part of the sentence we want to emphasize. It will still be clear what is meant because of the grammatical cases used:
Ich habe schon mal diesen Kuchen gegessen.
Diesen Kuchen have ich schon mal gegessen.
Gegessen habe ich diesen Kuchen schon mal.
Ich habe diesen Kuchen schon mal gegessen.
Ich habe die Zeitung im Park gelesen.
Die Zeitung habe ich im Park gelesen.
Gelesen habe ich die Zeitung im Park.
Ich habe im Park die Zeitung gelesen.

I think the second question is more about the different word order in “schon mal [adv] diesen Kuchen [obj]” vs “die Zeitung [obj] im Park [adv]”, rather than about possible ways to emphasise elements by fronting – i.e., would “Ich habe diesen Kuchen schon mal gegessen” or “Ich habe im Park die Zeitung gelesen” work equally as well?

Mir wurde Deutsch in der Schule gelehrt. ist falsch, da das Verb lehren mit zwei Akkusativobjekten steht. Es gibt kein Dativobjekt, daher kann auch im Passivsatz kein Dativobjekt vorkommen.

@Janka Auf https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Das-Verb-%E2%80%9Elehren%E2%80%9C steht: "Vor allem im 18. Jahrhundert war jedoch auch der Dativ gebräuchlich, also: Die Lehrerin lehrte den Kindern die Feinheiten der deutschen Sprache. Teilweise wird der Dativ auch heute noch benutzt. Interessanterweise ist er sogar der Fall der Wahl, wenn das Verb im Passiv verwendet wird: Ihnen wurden die Feinheiten der deutschen Sprache gelehrt.". Ich zweifle ein bisschen ob ich "Ich wurde lesen gelehrt." noch hinzufügen soll.

@Janka Der Duden listet den Dativ bei "lehren" zwar als "veraltend", erlaubt ihn aber. Von "falsch" kann also keine Rede sein.
